# find blue estimator of linear model in R

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I have the following linear model, and I'd want to find the Best linear unbiased estimator

```
x<-c(rep(c(1,0,-1,0),4),rep(c(0,1,0,-1),4),rep(c(1,1,0,0),4), rep(c(2,2,-1,-1),4))
x<-matrix(x,ncol=4,byrow=T) 
y<-c(2.1,1.9,2,2.2,1.2,0.8,1.1,0.9,5.1,5.2,4.9,4.9,7.9,8,8.2,7.9)
```

Comment: Have you tried fitting a linear model via lm()?

Comment: @TristanTao yes `lm(y~x)` but I get a NA in the last parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your fourth independent variable is a linear combination of the other three so it is omitted from the fit. To check this replace the fourth variable with `rnorm`.

```
x<-c(rep(c(1,0,-1,0),4),rep(c(0,1,0,-1),4),rep(c(1,1,0,0),4), rnorm(16))
x<-matrix(x,ncol=4,byrow=T) 
y<-c(2.1,1.9,2,2.2,1.2,0.8,1.1,0.9,5.1,5.2,4.9,4.9,7.9,8,8.2,7.9)

lm( y ~ x )


# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x1           x2           x3           x4  
#    6.0274       0.4742      -1.6753       4.5236       2.6643
```

Comment: but the parameters x1,x2,x3,x4 aren't the estimator with the minimum variance.